# IntelliJ Idea 12 - Java file is too large for editor

Tags: intellij-idea

Getting "`file x.java is too large for IntelliJ Idea editor`" after trying to open a web service stub class that is generated for Axis 2.

I saw a post associated about this issue which says change the

```
idea.max.intellisense.filesize=2500
```

in `idea.properties`.

But this trick didn't work for me despite I increased the value enough. Also I tried to comment out it for disabling this feature; but it didn't work too..

Comment: Any solution ever found for this problem? Running into the same error myself. I even set the file to be plain text and it still won't open.

Comment: no solution is found; seems it's not supported yet despite this parameter.

Answer (score 11):

Nowadays the setting

```
idea.max.intellisense.filesize=50000
```

works perfectly for me and lets me open files of up to 50M size.

Answer (score 8):

If you just want IntelliJ to open the full file instead of truncating it, use this:

```
idea.max.content.load.filesize=500000 #500MB
```

Answer (score 6):

My issue is that the file was > 20mb.  See this link: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85045